# Convert Decimal to Fraction Form method (Java)

Tags: java, decimal, fractions

I can't seem to find a simple method that converts a decimal value to fraction form. I need this method for use in a larger program, so the method should be passed a double value and return a string.

EDIT: sorry, new here. I just wanted an idea about how I'd go about making one. The examples i've seen assign their own values to be used. The method would look like

```
    public string convertype(double decimal){
      (Statements)
      return fraction;
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge, there is nos such already made function. You have to create it by yourself. 
Also, your question is not enough specific regarding SO standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Fraction {

     private int numerator, denominator;

     public Fraction(double decimal) {
         String stringNumber = String.valueOf(decimal);
         int numberDigitsDecimals = stringNumber.length() - 1 - stringNumber.indexOf('.');
         int denominator = 1;
         for (int i = 0; i < numberDigitsDecimals; i++) {
             decimal *= 10;
             denominator *= 10;
         }

        int numerator = (int) Math.round(decimal);
        int greatestCommonFactor = greatestCommonFactor(numerator, denominator);
        this.numerator = numerator / greatestCommonFactor;
        this.denominator = denominator / greatestCommonFactor;
     }

     public String toString() {
         return String.valueOf(numerator) + "/" + String.valueOf(denominator);
     }

     public static int greatestCommonFactor(int num, int denom) {
         if (denom == 0) {
             return num;
         }
         return greatestCommonFactor(denom, num % denom);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(new Fraction(0.75));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Trying to use this as an object in my methods class, any ideas on this?

Comment: @akhg2235  Only call a Fraction class instance in your method like this.                      `public string convertype(double decimal){
        return (new Fraction(decimal)).toString();
   }`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertype(0.75));
    }
    public static String convertype(double decimal){
      int digitsAfterPoint = String.valueOf(decimal).length() - String.valueOf(decimal).indexOf('.')+1; // get the count of digits after the point // for example 0.75 has two digits
      BigInteger numerator  = BigInteger.valueOf((long)(decimal*Math.pow(10, digitsAfterPoint))); // multiply 0.75 with 10^2 to get 75
      BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.valueOf((long)(Math.pow(10, digitsAfterPoint)));       // 10^2 is your denominator
      int gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator).intValue();                                           // calculate the greatest common divisor of numerator  and denominator
      if (gcd > 1 ){                                                                             // gcd(75,100) = 25
        return String.valueOf(numerator.intValue()/gcd) +" / "  + String.valueOf(denominator.intValue()/gcd);  // return 75/25 / 100/25 = 3/4
      }
      else{
        return String.valueOf(numerator) +" / "  + String.valueOf(denominator);              // if gcd = 1 which means nothing to simplify just return numerator / denominator  
      }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to convert a decimal number, you need to know the state of the situation before you convert it, let us say you have 0.333333, number 3 is being repeated infinitely. We all know that 0.333333 is 1/3 . Some people think that multiplying by the number of digits after the decimal point will convert it. That is completely false. It is something related mathematics, another situation is 0.25, take the numbers after the decimal point and divide them by 100 and simplify them, which equals to 1/4, completely true!

However, in mathematics we have 3 situations for converting a decimal number into a fraction, I am not going to explain them because It will take a lot of space and time, I have already written a program for this problem. This is the code :

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    static BigDecimal finalResult = new BigDecimal("0");

    static boolean check(short[] checks) {
        boolean isContinues = true;
        int index = -1;
        for (short ind : checks) {
            index++;
            if (ind==1) {

            }
            else if (ind==0) {
                isContinues = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (ind==-1) {
                if (index==0) {
                    isContinues = false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return isContinues;
    }
    static int[] analyzeDecimal() { // will return int[3]
        int[] analysis = new int[3];
        int dot = finalResult.toString().indexOf(".");
        String num = finalResult.toString();
        int state = -1;
        int firstPart = 0; // first part will be compared with each secondPart!
        int secondPart = 0; 
        String part = ""; // without the dot
        int index = 0; // index for every loop!
        int loop = 6;
        int originalLoop = loop;
        int size = 0; // until six!
        int ps = -1;
        short[] checks = new short[] {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}; // 10 compares for each part!
        // length of checks is 10!
        int continues = -1; // -1 means there is no continues part!
        boolean stop = false;
        while (true) { // while for size!
            if (size!=6) {
            while (true) { // we need to compare a part with a part!
                // while for loop
                // 6 loops, every loop will increase the compared part by 1!
                if (loop!=-1) { // TODO : check every part with the increasing pos
                    firstPart = dot+1+(originalLoop-loop); // changed
                    try {
                        part = num.substring(firstPart, firstPart+(size+1));
                    }
                    catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                        break;
                    }
                    int partSize = part.length();
                    int afterDecimal = num.length()-(dot+1);
                    while (index!=checks.length && 
                        firstPart+partSize+index*partSize-(dot+1)<=afterDecimal) { // while for index!
                        secondPart = firstPart+partSize+index*partSize;
                        String comparedPart;
                        try {
                            comparedPart = num.substring(secondPart, secondPart+partSize);
                        }
                        catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (part.equals(comparedPart)) {
                            checks[index] = 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            checks[index] = 0;
                        }
                        index++;
                    }
                    index = 0;
                    if (check(checks)) {
                        stop = true;
                        continues = firstPart;
                        ps = partSize;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0 ; i!=10 ; i++) {
                        checks[i] = -1;
                    }
                }
                else { // finished!
                    break;
                }
                loop--;
                if (stop) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            loop = originalLoop;
            size++;
            if (stop) {
                break;
            }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (continues==-1) {
            state = 2;
        }
        else {
            if (dot+1==continues) {
                state = 1;
            }
            else {
                state = 0;
            }
        }
        analysis[0] = state;
        analysis[1] = continues;
        analysis[2] = ps;

        return analysis;
    }
    static String convertToStandard() {
        // determine the state first : 
        int[] analysis = analyzeDecimal();
        int dot = finalResult.toString().indexOf('.')+1;
        int continues = analysis[1];
        int partSize = analysis[2]; // how many steps after the continues part
        if (analysis[0]==0) { // constant + continues
            String number = finalResult.toString().substring(0, continues+partSize);
            int numOfConst = continues-dot;
            int numOfDecimals = continues+partSize-dot;
            int den = (int)(Math.pow(10, numOfDecimals)-Math.pow(10, numOfConst)); // (10^numOfDecimals)-(10^numOfConst);
            int num;
            int toSubtract = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, dot-1)+number.substring(dot, dot+numOfConst));
            if (number.charAt(0)==0) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(dot));
            }
            else {
                num = Integer.parseInt(number.replace(".", ""));
            }
            num -= toSubtract;
            return simplify(num, den);
        }

        else if (analysis[0]==1) { // continues 
            int num, den;
            // we always have  to subtract by only one x!
            String n = finalResult.toString().substring(0, dot+partSize).replace(".", "");
            num = Integer.parseInt(n);
            den = nines(partSize);
            int toSubtract = Integer.parseInt(finalResult.toString().substring(0, dot-1));
            num -= toSubtract;
            return simplify(num, den);
        }
        else if (analysis[0]==2) { // constant
            partSize = finalResult.toString().length()-dot;
            int num = Integer.parseInt(finalResult.toString().replace(".", ""));
            int den = (int)Math.pow(10, partSize);
            return simplify(num, den);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("[Error] State is not determined!");
        }

        return "STATE NOT DETERMINED!";
    }
    static String simplify(int num, int den) {
        BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(num));
        BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(den));
        BigInteger GCD = n1.gcd(n2);
        String number = Integer.toString(num/GCD.intValue())+"/"+Integer.toString(den/GCD.intValue());

        return number;
    }
    static int nines(int n) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while (n!=0) {
            n--;
            result.append("9");
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(result.toString());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        finalResult = new BigDecimal("1.222222");
    }
}
```

The program above will give you an optimal result with high precision. All you have to do is change the finalResult variable in the main function.

Comment: I hope you appreciate my hard work to help the community.